# Extract a specific xml node using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have an xml data where there are multiple nodes with same name, however I just want to extract the value of one tag.

Sample XML:

```
<update>
    <family>
        <name>Rajesh</name>
        <age>35</age>
        <kids>
            <kid>
                <name>Manu</name>
                <age>2</age>
            </kid>
        </kids>
    </family>
</update>
```

I'm trying to extract the value of name tag from the family node but "name" value under kids sub-node is also getting selected.

```
$name = $(data).find("name");
```

This gives me "RajeshManu"

How do I select just value of "name" under family but not under "kids".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, you need to parse the XML before you can use jQuery.

```
$xml = $.parseXML(data);
```

Then you can use jQuery, to match elements inside the `$xml` object.

---

You could use `children()` instead of `find()`.

This is because `find()` will get all children and ancestors of the currently selected element. You want just the immediate child.

Using `children()` in the same way will give you just the immediate children which match the chosen selector.

For example:

```
$name = $xml.find('family').children('name');
```

---

Or you could match it using the `>` selector:

```
$name = $xml.find('family > name');
```